# Windows 8's File History tells me to "Reconnect your drive" when I try to clean up old backup data?

Tags: windows-8, backup, file-history

I was getting errors from File History telling me that the drive I've chosen to back everything up to is full. So I go into File History's advanced settings and click 'Clean up versions', which gets me this far:

[image: Cleanup window]

But when I pick an option and click 'Clean up', I get this error:

[image]

I'm not sure what exactly 'disconnected' is meant to mean though, because I can browse the drive from my computer just fine.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to delete some other stuff off the backup drive before running File History cleanup. It doesn't seem to work correctly if the disk is completely full (in my case, I had about 400kb free). It might also be possible to just directly delete the folder it creates and then go tell it to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have disconnected your USB drive. Then go to settings choose backup click to turn it on go to more options go to the bottom select stop using drive. then select see advanced settings and turn it back on this resets backup and it should start.